# What is an RPC port and how is it relevant to connecting to Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, rpc

Im not much of a networking type.  Im trying to understand how to debug a hadoop connection - and the connection relies on an RPC port.  Any insights into how an RPC port would effect a file URL in a Java program (not necessarily hadoop related ..) would be very helpfull here.....

Comment: RPC stands for [`Remote Procedure Call`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call).

Comment: 'debug a hadoop connection' - what do you mean by a hadoop connection? you would be able to debug hadoop programs in different ways.

Comment: Generally, I mean, that I cannot succesfully connect to haddop using the hdft:// protocol. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an RPC port is basically a way of identifying a machine and an "address" on that machine where a program is listening for some network connection and request.

RPC is the underlying protocol for doing this. In this case the higher level protocol is Hadoop but it could be something else - or something you've made up.